# Objective-C, How can i get the value of a UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, string, uitextfield

How can i get the value of a `UITextField`?
Some sample code to attach it to an `NSString` would be fab!

Comment: If i may, i think you are asking such simple questions, that maybe you should do some research before asking them on SO.

Comment: Also, you should accept the answers that are correct.

Comment: Good point, i did try - hate pissing off developers but apples documentation is pretty complicated :/

Comment: Stack overflow is a web site for any question about programming, no matter how simple. No need to downvote it just cos its basic. Its always nice to find a web site that answers your exact question without trawling through the api documentation when you are working things out.

Comment: This is NOT "such a simple question". Upvoting as it was a useful one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The UITextField has to be connected to your file through Interface Builder, and declared as an IBOutlet in your header file:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

Then you'd access it in your methods as:

```
NSString *enteredText = [textField text]; // Or textField.text
```

Comment: No it doesn't, you can build an entire interface from within code.

Comment: You're right; I didn't consider that the OP may be doing so. My mistake. It should be connected through as an IBOutlet if you are using Interface Builder to build the UI.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *tf_text = [ yourTextField text ];
```

Comment: In UIKit/Mobile Darwin, you can use properties as well: tf_text = yourTextField.text;

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt always look at the documentation it'll give you the answer faster than asking on here!

In this case: [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) and for future reference:
[iPhone class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Reference)